# If $E^\ast$ is the Alexandroff one-point compactification of $E$ and $f\in C(E^\ast)$, then $\left.f\right|_E-f(\infty)\in C_0(E)$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity

Let $E$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space, $E^\ast=E\cup\{\infty\}$ denote the Alexandroff one-point compactification of $E$, $f\in C(E^\ast)$ and $g:=\left.f\right|_E-f(\infty)$.

> How can we show that $g\in C_0(E)$?

The "reverse" of the claim is clear to me: If $h\in C_0(E)$, then $$h^\ast:E^\ast\to\mathbb R\;,\;\;\;x\mapsto\begin{cases}f(x)&\text{, if }x\in E\\0&\text{, if }x=\infty\end{cases}$$ is continuous.

Note that $g\in C_0(E)$ if and only if $g$ is continuous and $\left\{|g|\ge\varepsilon\right\}$ is compact for all $\varepsilon>0$. So, we might need a characterization of the compact sets in $E^\ast$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ is continuous at $\infty$ which means that for each $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $\infty$ such that $\lvert f(e) - f(\infty) \rvert <\varepsilon$ for all $e \in U$. But $U$ is an open neighborhood $\infty$ if and only if $K = E^* \setminus U$ is compact. This shows
$$M_\varepsilon  = \{ e \in E \mid \lvert g(e) \rvert \ge \varepsilon \} \subset K .$$
Hence $M_\varepsilon$ is compact.

Comment: The topology on $E^\ast$ is $\tau^\ast:=\tau\cup\left\{E\setminus K\cup\left\{\infty\right\}:K\subseteq E\text{ is compact}\right\}$, where $\tau$ denotes the topology on $E$. So, I guess we can argue that since $U$ is open and $\infty\in U$, there is a compact $K\subseteq E$ with $U=E\setminus K\cup\left\{\infty\right\}$. Then obviously $E^\ast\setminus U=K$. Right?

Comment: Oh, and while it's clear to me that a closed subspace of a compact space is compact, it's not clear to me why $M_\varepsilon$ is closed. Sure, the argument is that $g$ is continuous, but why is $g$ continuous?

Comment: The map $G= f - f(\infty) : E^* \to \mathbb R$ is continuous, hence $g$ as the restriction of $G$ is continuous.

Comment: The restriction of a continuous map is continuous, sure, but with respect to a fixed topology. So, this only yields that $g$ is $\tau^\ast$-continuous.

Comment: Now I see your problem. But note that the topology induced by $\tau^*$ on the subset $E \subset E^*$ is nothing else than $\tau$. In fact $((E \setminus K) \cup \{\infty\}) \cap E =  E \setminus K \in \tau$.

Comment: Ah, sure. Thank you.